Android Emulator is not starting or booting up in Android Studio Jellyfish 2023.3.1. What can I do to run the emulator?
Today, I updated my Android Studio to new update from iguana to jellyfish version. I checked the emulator in case of any error would happen and certainly does happened.The Android emulator AVD has no configuration file and when I tried to install a new AVD. It doesn't work also.

You appear to have "accepted" an answer below that is not an answer. Answers here should be a full solution to the question. Please unaccept that and accept another one (if there is a good answer).

My issue is that this happens sometimes and I have to restart my PC....It is annoying.

Same Issue here, restarted pc didn't work, created a new emulator and deleted old one, still no use, nothing seems to work. I even posted on LinkedIn for Google and linked to this post. this is beyond annoying.

Ok, I was facing the same issue here. I deleted the other devices and created a new one.
Specs:
UpsideDownCake Android 14.0 x86_64
Emulated Performance - Graphics: Software
Boot option: Cold Boot
Although I'm not able to pin down the problem it's working for me.
To create new devices in case someone reading this don't know: https://developer.android.com/studio/run/emulator#avd

You are actually correct.I did try to delete my  old avd and install new .But the whole avd windows is not opening that is the problem.It just shows spin animation when I click the start or play button

For me the Graphs is grayed out

Same issue, i started the emulator from command line using the parameter -gpu swiftshader_indirect, i.e.
C:\Users\$YOUR_USERNAME$\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\emulator\emulator.exe -netdelay none -netspeed full -no-snapstorage -avd $YOUR_AVD_NAME$ -gpu swiftshader_indirect

Finally the emulator started, i opened the Extended Controls window (three vertical dots icon), choose Settings and choose in OpenGL ES the value Autodetect.
After that i was able to open all AVD's i had without having to repeat the above steps.

so I have fixed this just by installing Latest Microsoft Visual C++ Redistributable Version
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/windows/latest-supported-vc-redist?view=msvc-170#visual-studio-2015-2017-2019-and-2022
It seems that latest AVD emulators depends from these Microsoft Libs, really strange to me. Why Google based their AVD's on these Microsoft Visual C++ Redistributable Libs, I don't know.
NOTE:
It's strange that someone market this answer with minus, because I do the same twice and it's work after installing these Microsoft Visual C++ 2015-2022 Redistributable (x64)
